# ionic v3 bind ionic page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic3

I am binding to ionic input component to html page from ts file. it is showing only text.

My html code is:

```
<div class="one" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div>
```

My ts file code is:

```
constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,public navCtrl: NavController, 
public navParams: NavParams) {

 }
 this.htmlToAdd =this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(  "<ion-label>Gaming</ion-label><ion-select [(ngModel)]='gaming'><ion-option value='nes'>NES</ion-option><ion-option value='n64' >Nintendo64</ion-option></ion-select>");
```

Output is:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I guess only the HTML known elements could be binded by using `[innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"`& not the ionic elements.